# Display full month calendar on tool bar date/time click?

Tags: mac, osx-lion

How can I get a full calendar view of the current month when clicking on the date time in the menu bar?  Windows does something similar if you click on the date time in the menu bar it displays the current month full calendar.

Any info is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/):

[image]

Comment: Yes good suggestion and it does a lot of other monitoring which is useful.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Does it slow your system down at all?

Comment: Why should I donwload extra package for this simple feature? I thought I hate windows, I was wrong, VERY wrong...